# How to add javascript external file like bootstrap , jQuery to reactjs app

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am new to ReactJs, I have `bootstrap.min.js`, `jquery.min.js`, `etc` static file in my assets folder. I have to add those file to my ReactJs App, I had tried but it's not working.

I had added the below code to the **index.html** but it's not working

```
<script src="./assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/vendor/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Install bootstrap and jQuery using `npm install bootstrap jquery --save` and use them in your app.

Comment: Check more here https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap and https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery

Answer (score 3):

The best way which I have used is  via npm (yarn) package which you can directly install bootstrap into your project

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

Other users have mentioned using `npm install <package>`. If you've used `create-react-app` (or have yarn installed) I wanted to add that you can also use `yarn add <package>` for jQuery. Both work well.

Comment: If you have yarn installed